# How can I resize the height of an image to crop with the browser window?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, web, resize-image

I have an image that I want to cover the full window of my browser upon loading the website. I've got it so that, as the width of the browser window increases or decreases, the image is resized while preserving the center alignment and aspect ratio by cropping out on either side. However, I want it so that, as the height of the browser window increases or decreases, the image is cropped **from the bottom** so that the bottom of the image always lines up with the bottom of the browser window and the top of the image is never cut off. In other words, when I scroll down, there should be no more image beneath the browser window to scroll over. I have the following HTML and CSS code:

HTML:

```
 <div class="hs-slide hs-slide-count<?php echo $i; ?>">
      <div class="hs-slide-overlay"></div>
      <img src="<?php echo esc_url($hashone_slider_image); ?>" class="banner">
      <div class="hs-slide-caption">
        <div class="hs-slide-cap-title animated fadeInLeft">
          <?php echo esc_html($hashone_slider_title); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="hs-slide-cap-desc animated fadeInRight">
          <?php echo esc_html($hashone_slider_subtitle); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
img.banner{
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Set up positioning */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.banner {
left: 50%;
margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

How can I do this, ideally without JavaScript? Also, I got the CSS from a guide on filling the browser window with an image, and I don't know why the min-width in the HTML is specifically set to 1024px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

**Example**: https://jsfiddle.net/jbx8nco4/4/

**Description specific to your code:** You need to remove the `<img>` inside the `.hs-slide` container and instead use a background-image. After adding the background-image to `.hs-slide` (see code below), the `.hs-slide` element needs a height to be visible. You can either explicitly set one or let the element adapt to the height of its content. For the latter you would need to remove all positioning from `.hs-slide-caption` and give it a padding-top and padding-bottom. For simplicity I've set an explicit height in the example:

```
.hs-slide {
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/1000/500); /* replace with your image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center top;
}
```

The shorthand notation of this code would be:

```
background: url(//placekitten.com/1000/500) center top / cover no-repeat;
```

The `background-attachment: fixed` I mentioned in the first version of my comment is not needed as you want the image to scroll with your page.

By the way: as you have two background-images now, one being part of the `.hs-slide-overlay`, you could try getting rid of the overlay by combining the two background-images by using [the notation for multiple background-images](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/#article-header-id-3).

## Old answer:

I am not completely sure but it sounds like what you want can be achieved by using a CSS `background-image`. I can't think of a Javascript-free solution using the HTML `img` tag.

You need to add the background-image to any element that stretches to the full width and height of the viewport and then set the appropriate attributes, most importantly `background-size` and `background-position`.

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(//placekitten.com/1000/500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover; // cover the whole area with the image
  background-position: top; // expand image from the top
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

The shorthand version for the background properties would be:

```
background-image: url(//placekitten.com/1000/500) no-repeat top fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/jbx8nco4/2/

Keep in mind, that `background-size: cover` is not supported by older browsers.

For further information and more techniques on using background-images for covering the full page see: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: With this solution, does this mean the image won't scroll with the page? I don't want the image to be a permanent background that persists through the entire page. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just noticed that my example was the other way around, you said you want to fix the image at the top, so the bottom may be cropped. I've updated the code accordingly. Besides that, I'm not sure if I understood you right. Do you have any example page with a similar effect? Do you want something like [parallax scrolling](https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/)?

Comment: [Here](http://austinwu.com) is an example of a website with what I want, except that it also crops from the top. But, you can see that the background image always aligns with the bottom of the browser window on the splash screen, the jsfiddle looks like what I want, so I'm going to try to implement it now.

Comment: Thank you for the example, now I see what you want. My solution was quite close to this but the `background-attachment: fixed` was wrong. I have updated the answer with code fitting to your page. Regarding the URL for the background image, you can either use a relative or an absolute (including the `http://`) URL, depending where the image is on your server

Comment: Nice! If my answer helped you, feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.